# can you give me a website that has a list of prices for old mtg cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a lot of magic cards from year 2009-2000 and i want to sell them but i dont know which one of my cards have value but i dont know if there is a website that has a list of old mtg cards that still has monetary value or can be sold.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doens't concern a game's mechanics.

Comment: @steenbergh This site is definitely not limited strictly to questions about game mechanics. We've had previous questions about organizing and selling cards, questions about lore associated with games, questions about tournaments, game identification questions...

Answer (score 1):

On [mtggoldfish](http://mtggoldfish.com) you can find the prices of all cards printed and online